# AlertDialog.Builder shows null from API Request

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am starting to learn to develop an android app (hopefully I can understand this awesome technology).

I have a Rest API that I build myself with PHP.

The case is, the android app scan a QR-Code and then send the resultScan to my Rest API.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class InfoCoilActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private String responseResult;

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Result Scan For Info Coil");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(InfoCoilActivity.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage("Result " + handleRequestApi(scanResult));
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public String handleRequestApi(String textCode) {
        String URL = "http://my-web.com/api/morowali-coil/" + textCode;
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        responseResult = response.toString();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        responseResult = error.toString();
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return responseResult;
    }
}
```

Please see in `builder.setMessage("Result " + handleRequestApi(scanResult));`
When I scan the qr code in first shot, I got message

```
Result null
```

I try to see in logcat, in the first shot, successfully get the response json like this:

```
10-17 14:07:01.492 11568-11568/com.dzil.myapplication E/Rest Response:: {"id":889,"coil_number":"QLZ18K01014A","planning_delivery":"WAREHOUSE","billet_number":"Y180908B03-4","width":0,"thickness":"0.00","grade":"S30403","size":"1.84*1250*C","actual_size":"1.85*1249","quantity":1,"nett":20930,"gross":21016,"customer":"IIS","contract_number":"IRNC18\/CC1137","procurement_contract_number":"","white_roll_number":"N1809100738","production_date":"2018-09-21","standard_eksekutif":"EN 10028-7","order_number":"ET18\/CC708001-IIS","unstuffing_plan":"2018-10-14","length":1143,"production_warehouse":"6#库","port":"Surabaya","vessel":null,"vessel_id":2,"urut":889,"lokasi":null,"lokasi_terakhir":null,"nama_file":"Copy of morowali-surabaya-example-format-data","created_by":"1","updated_by":"1","created_at":"2018-10-12 16:09:46","updated_at":"2018-10-12 16:09:46"}
```

But when I try again in second shot, it normal that I got those json like json above

```
Result {"id":889,"coil_number":"QLZ18K01014A","planning_delivery":"WAREHOUSE","billet_number":"Y180908B03-4","width":0,"thickness":"0.00","grade":"S30403","size":"1.84*1250*C","actual_size":"1.85*1249","quantity":1,"nett":20930,"gross":21016,"customer":"IIS","contract_number":"IRNC18\/CC1137","procurement_contract_number":"","white_roll_number":"N1809100738","production_date":"2018-09-21","standard_eksekutif":"EN 10028-7","order_number":"ET18\/CC708001-IIS","unstuffing_plan":"2018-10-14","length":1143,"production_warehouse":"6#库","port":"Surabaya","vessel":null,"vessel_id":2,"urut":889,"lokasi":null,"lokasi_terakhir":null,"nama_file":"Copy of morowali-surabaya-example-format-data","created_by":"1","updated_by":"1","created_at":"2018-10-12 16:09:46","updated_at":"2018-10-12 16:09:46"}
```

Please advice!

Answer (score 2):

`handleRequestApi` is an asynchronous method, meaning that it returns **before** getting any value from your API.

So `return responseResult` will always return the initial value of null.

see: [Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)
for more information about asynchronous tasks

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like this because of asynchronism. The first shot returns null because the `handleRequestApi()` method does not have the response of the request. The second shot returns something because of cache.

To use asynchronism correctly, you have to manage your response directly in the 
`onResponse()` callback. You want to display an AlertDialog ? Do something like this

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    responseResult = response.toString();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(InfoCoilActivity .this);
    builder.setTitle("Result Scan For Info Coil");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(InfoCoilActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage("Result " + response);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog was created immediately without waiting for the response because the function `handleRequestApi(scanResult)` was called asynchronously, therefore it showed null instead because the initial value of `responseResult` in your activity was null at the time.

To fix this, you should create the dialog only when it receives the response:

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(...)
            .setPositiveButton(...)
            .setMessage(response.toString())
            .create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of asynchronisity in using volley and alert dialog. You can create a custom interface like below code:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener{
    void onVolleyResponse(String response);        
}
```

and use it in your codes.

```
public class InfoCoilActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler, VolleyResponseListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private String responseResult;
    private VolleyResponseListener volleyResponseListener;

public interface VolleyResponseListener{
    void onVolleyResponse(String response);        
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        volleyResponseListener = (VolleyResponseListener) this;

        //... your codes...

    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        handleRequestApi(result.getText());

    }

    public void handleRequestApi(String textCode) {
        String URL = "http://my-web.com/api/morowali-coil/" + textCode;
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        volleyResponseListener.onVolleyResponse(response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        volleyResponseListener.onVolleyResponse(error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVolleyResponse(String response){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Result Scan For Info Coil");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(InfoCoilActivity.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setMessage("Result " + response);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

**Notice:** I've add and remove some codes. Be carefull about `implements` and `onCreate`.